# compareGroups table with knitr - how to adjust table head and subtext?

Tags: r, statistics, latex, knitr, sweave

I just discovered the wonderful package compareGroups and I think this may help me a lot in the future. So far, it is working brilliantly in combination with Knitr/Sweave:

```
\documentclass{article}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% LaTeX packages needed for compareGroups

% long tables
\usepackage{longtable}

% multi row
\usepackage{multirow}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

% R code
<<results = "asis">>=

library(compareGroups)

# Very short code for bivariate descriptive table
tab <- compareGroups(vs ~ . , data = mtcars)
export2latex(createTable(tab))

@

\end{document}
```

produces
[image]

I have only two concerns which is i) the modification of the table head (e.g. I want to print "P value" instead of "p.overall") and ii) adding a multicolumn subtext (e.g. "t-test was used to calculate P values."). If I just exported the table to LaTeX Code, it would be easy to modify head and subtext but in combination with Knitr I don't know how to deal with it. I just really would appreciate this wonderful solution over laborious functions in combination with e.g. Xtables package.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concern i) can be dealt with by manually reassigning the name of the 3rd column of matrix `tab$descr` prior to calling `export2latex`. Concern ii) might be addressed alternatively by placing the text in a caption (it seems to me more appropriate -- and further I have no idea about how to stick that into a multicol subheader).

```
tab <- compareGroups(vs ~ . , data = mtcars)
tab <- createTable(tab)
colnames(tab$descr)[3] <- "P value"
export2latex(tab, caption="$t$-test was used to calculate $p$ values.",
             loc.caption="bottom")
```

Regarding your request (below) to add, in fact, two captions (a numbered caption above the table and a non-numbered explanatory sub-text below the table), one way to achieve this is to encapsulate the `longtable` produced by `export2latex` within a (possibly centered) `minipage` environment, and placing the second caption as ordinary text below the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

See Table~\ref{tab:complicated} for the main results of this paper.
\begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}[c]{0.5\textwidth}

<<results = "asis", echo=FALSE>>=

library(compareGroups)

tab <- compareGroups(vs ~ . , data = mtcars)
tab <- createTable(tab)
colnames(tab$descr)[3] <- "P value"
export2latex(tab, caption="Characteristics of the patients at baseline$^*$.",
             label="tab:complicated"
             )
@
{\footnotesize $^*$A two-sided $t$-test was used to calculate the $p$ values.}
\end{minipage} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

References:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15282/tabular-title-above-and-caption-below

Comment: Thanks so much, Renato. The "P value" part was quite simple. The 2nd issue is due to requirements in some biomedical journals such as NEJM. There is usually a short table heading and a more comprehensive subtext as you can see here (http://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa1601747?query=featured_home). But perhaps one should embed the table in a center environment or the like and add the subtext below the R code..

Comment: Added a temptative solution to your request. For further customisation, I suggest that you save the table to an external LaTeX file and edit it manually: you can achieve this by including an argument `file="name_file_tab.tex"` to the `export2latex()` call